# How do I make elements with float not line break and extend outside their parent container?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am stumped. I am trying to make a set of icons that sit inside a container with a fixed width. The elements must be inside the parent container but must extend beyond the boundary and not line break when they reach the right border of the parent.

I am using Floated li elements

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJydR/2/)

Would like it to look like this.

[image]

Not this:

[image]

Thanks for any Help.

Here is the Code:

```
<div class="mainFooter">
<div class="iconContainer">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Services"><a class="icon-th-list icon-white">A</a>
        </li>
        <li class="" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Assets"><a class="icon-briefcase icon-white">B</a>
        </li>
        <li class="" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Clients"><a class="icon-group icon-white">C</a>
        </li>
        <li class="" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Reports"><a class="icon-dashboard icon-white">D</a>
        </li>
        <li class="" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Preferences"><a class="icon-cogs icon-white">E</a>
        </li>
        <li class="" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Assets"><a class="icon-briefcase icon-white">F</a>
        </li>
        <li class="" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Assets"><a class="icon-briefcase icon-white">G</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
 .mainFooter {
    background: #dddddd;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    width:30%;

    }
.iconContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid red;
    top:5px;
}
.mainFooter .nav > li{
    float:left;
}
.mainFooter .nav > li > a {
    padding:0px;
    margin: 1px;
    height:25px;
    width:30px;
    background:#2f65bb;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 130%;
    line-height: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`.white-space: nowrap` on the `<ul>`.  Do not float the elements, but use `display: inline-block`.

http://jsfiddle.net/nJydR/3/

Comment: Ok great but what if I want the same thing going from right to left starting from exactly the right edge?

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat float the container.

Answer (score 0):

you may try to setup fixed width for `.nav-pills`, something like

```
.nav-pills {
  width: 230px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nJydR/4/

Comment: Possible but it may be any size and I don't want it extending beyond it's intended width

Comment: okay, I just went from fact that in your question you mentioned fixed width for parent container